# Apache PdfBox - MultiLine Content being overwritten while writing into pdf

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I need to create a pdf that contains multi-line content. I am able  to create the pdf successfully. However there are some portion that are being overwritten. I have tried using `contentStream.newLine()` but it does not work. I am not sure what am i missing. Could you please let me know how to rectify this.

Below  is the generated pdf:
[Generated PDF Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BRG6.png)

Below is the code :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font;


public class PDFGen {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
            PDPage page = new PDPage(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle.A4);
            document.addPage(page);

            generateContent(document);

            document.save("output.pdf");
            document.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void generateContent(PDDocument document) throws IOException {
        PDPage page = document.getPage(0);


        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
        contentStream.setFont(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);
        float margin = 50;
        float yStart = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - margin;
        float yPosition = yStart;
        float bottomMargin = 70;
        float width = page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - 2 * margin;
        List<String> lines = getSampleText(); // Your content goes here

        for (String line : lines) {
            if (yPosition - bottomMargin < 0) {
                contentStream.close();
                page = new PDPage(org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDRectangle.A4);
                document.addPage(page);
                contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page, PDPageContentStream.AppendMode.APPEND, true);
                yStart = page.getMediaBox().getHeight() - margin;
                yPosition = yStart;
            }

            drawText(contentStream, line, margin, yPosition, width);
            yPosition -= 25; // Adjust line height
        } 

        contentStream.close();
    }

    private static void drawText(PDPageContentStream contentStream, String text, float x, float y, float width) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        int lastSpace = -1;

        while (text.length() > 0) {
            int spaceIndex = text.indexOf(' ', lastSpace + 1);
            if (spaceIndex < 0)
                spaceIndex = text.length();
            String subString = text.substring(0, spaceIndex);
            float size = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD.getStringWidth(subString) / 1000 * 12;
            if (size > width) {
                if (lastSpace < 0)
                    lastSpace = spaceIndex;
                subString = text.substring(0, lastSpace);
                lines.add(subString);
                text = text.substring(lastSpace).trim();
                lastSpace = -1;
            } else if (spaceIndex == text.length()) {
                lines.add(text);
                text = "";
            } else {
                lastSpace = spaceIndex;
            }
        }
        
        contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);

        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.newLineAtOffset(x, y);
        for (String line : lines) {
            contentStream.showText(line);
            contentStream.newLine();
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -12); // Adjust line height
        }
        contentStream.endText();
    }

    private static List<String> getSampleText() {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
         lines.add("1.1.");
         lines.add("Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.ffffffff");
         lines.add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.");
         lines.add("qwertyu");
         lines.add("1.2.");
         lines.add("Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercit");
         lines.add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.");
         lines.add("qwertyu");
         lines.add("1.3.");
         lines.add("Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercit");
         lines.add("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.");
         lines.add("qwertyu");
         
        return lines;
    }
}
```

Comment: The lines might be too long. Do you want them to be wrapped?

Comment: Hi Stefan, yes i need lines to be wrapped.

Comment: You're using `newLine()` (without ever having called `setLeading()`) and `newLineAtOffset()`, this is weird. What happens if you just remove `newLine`?

Comment: Hi @TilmanHausherr, what i have noticed is that if i remove `newLine` the next line gets overwritten a bit more towards the upside. Also i read in one of the blog that `setLeading()` is used to set the height of the line. Does that mean i am setting the height wrong?

Comment: I looked at some code of mine, I used `setLeading(fontSize * 1.2f);` So yes, y offset delta 12 is wrong for font size 12, it should multiplied with a factor. `TextToPDF` uses `1.05` which seems low but nobody has ever complained.

Comment: You assume a constant height of 25 per line drawn: `yPosition -= 25;` but if you have to break the line more often than once, that isn't enough. Consider returning from `drawText` how often you had to break the line and then subtract from `drawText` accordingly.

Comment: Of course that doesn't take end-of-page into account. I'm afraid your architecture as is with its `drawText` method is made for "lines" that indeed fit into a single line or at most into 2. Consider breaking your text first into lines of appropriate length and then start to draw these actual lines onto pages.

Comment: Oh ok, that can be one of the approach, breaking the lines beforehand on certain length. I will try that and come back to  you

Answer (score 0):

Change code to:

```
contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);

        contentStream.beginText();
        
        for (String line : lines) {
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(x, y);
            contentStream.showText(line);
        }
        contentStream.endText();
```

Comment: Hello, when i change the code as suggested above, the wrapping of text gets vanished. And some of the content does not get written.  What i need that the extra line should be wrapped and the new line should not get overwritten.

Comment: The line with `newLineAtOffset` should probably be `contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -12);`. The line with (x, y) is missing and should be put back at the beginning. Another problem is that you need to take into account how much you moved, to avoid overlapping paragraphs. There is code that converts from text to PDF in the source code (TextToPDF.java) and properly wraps text.